# Importing multi space delimited file

Tags: r, import

Good day,

I'm trying to import data from text file to R. Properly formatted data is no issue, but what to do when delimiter is double/triple space?

For example I have following data in text format

```
Var1    Var2    var3
30000   Sedan   Model 2014
30000   CHEVROLET   Corvette Stingray
....
```

In this instead of \t (tab) delimited it is three space (   ) delimited. Also the data in column may contain single spaces.

How to make R accept this directly?

I've tried **read.table**, but separator identifier (sep="") does not seem to accept multiple characters and Regular expressions are not supported. (As far as I know.) What seems to work is to read the data in as tab delimited and splitting it once it's in dataframe, but this is silly.

Comment: I have just tried the package `data.table` with the function `fread` but it does also only allow one character as separator ("`'sep' must be 'auto' or a single character`"

Comment: Using `fread(input = text, sep = " ", header = F, strip.white = T)` does also not work if a space occurs within data of a character column

Comment: Package `readr` does not help neither: `x <- read_delim(text, delim = "   ", trim_ws = T)` allows only one character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::separate` to split the data into columns by three spaces.

```
df <- read.table(text = "Var1    Var2    var3
30000   Sedan   Model 2014
30000   CHEVROLET   Corvette Stingray", sep = "%", skip = 1)

tidyr::separate(df, V1, c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3"), sep = "\\s{3}", )

 Var1      Var2              Var3
1 30000     Sedan        Model 2014
2 30000 CHEVROLET Corvette Stingray
```

Comment: Tested and confirmed to work. Small addition for copy-pasters:  Had to add extra enter to text = *enter* "var1 ...

Answer (score 2):

Exact problem is that your column separator(2 or more spaces) and separator within column values (single space) are overlapping.

To read this correctly segregate the two.

Regex for 2 or more spaces is `\s{2,}`.

Use this regex to convert column separators into `,` using `gsub`.

Read the converted text directly via `read.csv`

```
>rawText="Var1    Var2    var3
30000   Sedan   Model 2014
30000   CHEVROLET   Corvette Stingray"

>cleanedText=gsub("\\s{2,}",",",rawText)

>df<-read.table(text=cleanedText)

> df
   Var1      Var2              var3
1 30000     Sedan        Model 2014
2 30000 CHEVROLET Corvette Stingray
```